# Looping a sprite infinitely in Cocos2D

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm making a vertical-scroll platformer game, and I want to create sprites that move left-to-right (or right-to-left) and when they're out of the screen, they appear on the other side.

I have an implementation that is *mostly* working, the only problem is that the sprites on a single *floor* keeps getting closer and closer in every loop.

I'm really not good in describing things, so [please check this video](https://jumpshare.com/v/Cr8nCDHNhdjhhZi7Aehh).

I'm using the following code to calculate the new position of the nodes:

```
pos.x = fmodf(size.width + pos.x + this->currentDir * this->speed * delta, this->len + size.width) - size.width;
```

`len` is the width after which the sprite gets repositioned to `0` (actually `-size.width`, which is the width of the sprite), `currentDir` is either `1` or `-1` and `delta` is the time from the update() method.

Every sprite is positioned in it's own update(), but I already tried doing everything in the Scene's update() method, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your delta variable is increasing over time, then I believe that your pos.x would also increase in the same proportion, this is why the distance from the floors would change.

Have you tried to reset the delta value each time the floor goes offscreen?

Comment: delta is the time elapsed since the previous call of update() in seconds

Comment: Hi, I understood that. I believe that one of your variables is growing more over time than it should and I thought it might be the delta if you are not resetting it. I suggest that you print the values you have over time to see where is the problem.